Access the list of data from another function
I have created a function for reading the data from excel file and stored as a list by rows and columns. Now I want use or access the data from the list to another functions using C#
public static void ReadExcelData(string filepath)
{
    try
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;

        object[,] data = new object[rowCount, colCount];

        // Loop through each cell in the range and store the data in the array
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                data[i - 1, j - 1] = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value;
            }
        }

        List<List<object>> newData = new List<List<object>>();

        // Access the data by rows and columns
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            List<object> newRow = new List<object>();
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
            {
                newRow.Add(data[i, j]);
            }
            newData.Add(newRow);
        }

        excelWorkbook.Close(false);
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
    catch (NXException ex)
    {
        theSession.LogFile.WriteLine("+++ Error Found in 'Main' : " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}


return newData from your function.

Thanks. I will use return newData. It is storing values as expected. But now how to access particularly. for example: if the excel data have "Drawing_Required" in row and "YES" in column. How to get know these values by accessing the values by using it another function?

public static List<List<object>> ReadExcelData(string filepath)
{
    List<List<object>> newData = new List<List<object>>();
    try
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;

        object[,] data = new object[rowCount, colCount];

        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                data[i - 1, j - 1] = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            List<object> newRow = new List<object>();
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
            {
                newRow.Add(data[i, j]);
            }
            newData.Add(newRow);
        }

        excelWorkbook.Close(false);
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // Changed from NXException to Exception for broader error handling
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        return null; // return null or throw, depending on how you want to handle errors
    }
    return newData;
}

change the signature of the ReadExcelData method to return a List<List<object>>
public static string GetValueBasedOnCriteria(List<List<object>> data, string searchColumn, string searchValue)
{
    int columnIndex = -1;

    // First, find the index of the column that contains the header 'searchColumn'
    for (int i = 0; i < data[0].Count; i++)
    {
        if (data[0][i].ToString() == searchColumn)
        {
            columnIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the column was found, look for the row containing the 'searchValue' in that column
    if (columnIndex != -1)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < data.Count; j++) // start from 1 to skip header row
        {
            if (data[j][columnIndex].ToString() == searchValue)
            {
                return "Value found: " + searchValue + " in column " + searchColumn;
            }
        }
    }

    return "Value not found";
}

Usage:
var excelData = ReadExcelData("path_to_your_excel_file.xlsx");

// Now, use the function to find a specific value
string result = GetValueBasedOnCriteria(excelData, "Drawing_Required", "YES");
Console.WriteLine(result);


Thanks. I will use return newData. It is storing values as expected. But now how to access particularly. for example: if the excel data have "Drawing_Required" in row and "YES" in column. How to get know these values by accessing the values by using it another function?

@Anand Please Check I have modified the Answer. I hope it helps You

Thanks a lot. It works and I have learned it from you today.
